# PowerShell -is operator always matching PSCustomObject when used in ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-v6.0

Using PowerShell Core 6.1 on Mac.  It appears that piping an array to ForEach-Object is modifying or wrapping each element such that the -is operator considers  all of them to be PSCustomObjects.

Let me demonstrate:

Set up an array of four items of different types (use of JSON because that's where the data is coming from in my real use case):

```
$a = '[4, "Hi", {}, true]' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Iterate the list by index and determine which ones are PSCustomObjects:

```
0..3 | ForEach-Object { 
    $v = $a[$_]
    $t = $v.GetType().FullName
    $is = $v -is [PSCustomObject]
    "$t - $is"
}
```

The output (for me) is exactly what I would expect:

```
System.Int64 - False
System.String - False
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject - True
System.Boolean - False
```

But if I just pipe the array to ForEach-Object:

```
$a | ForEach-Object { 
    $v = $_
    $t = $v.GetType().FullName
    $is = $v -is [PSCustomObject]
    "$t - $is"
}
```

Now the output claims that all four are PSCustomObjects:

```
System.Int64 - True
System.String - True
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject - True
System.Boolean - True
```

Could anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: `[PSCustomObject]` is an alias for `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]`, but not to `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`. So, that means that all four are wrapped into `[PSObject]` inside `ForEach-Object` cmdlet. Likely because `InputObject` parameter of `ForEach-Object` typed as `[PSObject]` and `ForEach-Object` does not do unwrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), as he frequently does, has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

**Piping objects to `ForEach-Object` wraps them in a `[psobject]` instance (as reflected in `$_` / `$PSItem`), which causes `-is [pscustomobject]` / `-is [psobject]` to return `$True` for *any* input object**, because - confusingly - `[pscustomobject]` is the same as `[psobject]`: they're both type accelerators for `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]` - against what one would expect,`[pscustomobject]` is *not* short for `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`.

Therefore, **test the input objects for being instances of `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`** rather than `[pscustomobject]`:

```
$a | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]
}
```

Note that if you use a `foreach` *loop*, even `-is [pscustomobject]` would work, because the objects being enumerated are then *not* wrapped in an extra `[psobject]` instance:

```
foreach ($element in $a) {
  $element -is [pscustomobject]
}
```

This works, because even a bona fide `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]` is *technically* also a `[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]` behind the scenes.